# Simultaneous gestures and scaling of pinch Gesture in swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, gesture

Hopeing for a bit of enlightenment. I have a piece of code. Which is working fairly OK.
I have 2 gestures implemented -  pinch and rotate.

```
let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pinchAction(sender:)))
view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
pinchGesture.delegate = self
let rotateGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotateAction(sender:)))
view.addGestureRecognizer(rotateGesture)
rotateGesture.delegate = self
```

and then this function which I found here on another thread.

```
   func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if (gestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer || gestureRecognizer is UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

my class is set to

```
class GameScene: SKScene, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
```

so my first question is. How the heck is this function actually being called? Is it automatically called because it's called gestureRecognizer? I don't call it elsewhere as a function in my code. Sorry just find it confusing.

the other interesting issue is that as I rescale my SKSprite node with the pinch function I want it to not jump back to the scale of the initial pinch. I have set a variable for the scale of the node being adjusted and take that in the pinch began and also adjust the variable when pinch ends as so:

```
 @objc func pinchAction(sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
        if sender.state == .began{
            //print("Pinch Began")
            pointer.setScale(CGFloat(protractorScale * 0.5))
            protractor.setScale(CGFloat(protractorScale * 0.45))

        }
        if sender.state == .changed{
           // print("Pinch Change")
            let newScale = sender.scale
            protractorScale = Double(newScale)
            print(newScale)
            pointer.setScale(CGFloat(protractorScale * 0.5))
            protractor.setScale(CGFloat(protractorScale * 0.45))
            ballSpeed = Float(newScale * 500)
        }
        if sender.state == .ended{
           // print("Pinch Ended")

            let newScale = sender.scale
                       protractorScale = Double(newScale)


        }
    }
```

but it still jumps to whatever pinch position I start with while it ought to stay stable between individual pinches rather than reseting.

I appreciate my code is simplistic so am also open to suggestions for a tighter code. This is my first attempt at using simultaneous gestures.Thanks

Comment: 1)That is how delegates work.... the UI is going to look for all delegates assigned and call the function.

Comment: 2) You need to account for the scale every time and retain it.  I do not know why your begin always chops the scale in half.... that is weird.  What you need to do is on begin, capture and retain the original scale of the node; on change and end, multiply the pinch scale by the retain value scale and assign it back to the node. On end, release the retain value (Technically this is optional)

Comment: OK I understand. What I hadn't realised fully is that the initial pinch scale factor is of course always 1 however you begin the pinch. So I had all kinds of scaling factors going on that sent it screwy. Smooth as a baby now! Is etiquette that I put a working code back in my original post now? Still getting used to things here and would like to show the solution.

Comment: Answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood that obviously the pinch gesture always initially returns a pinch scale factor of 1. Obviously! Once I realised that and after KnightOfDragon's advice it was straightforward.

```
   @objc func pinchAction(sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
        if sender.state == .began{

            let startScale = sender.scale
            print("initial pinch scale \(startScale)")

            pointer.setScale(CGFloat(protractorScale))
            protractor.setScale(CGFloat(protractorScale))

        }
        if sender.state == .changed{

            let getScale = sender.scale
            print(getScale)

            let newScale = (CGFloat(protractorScale) * getScale)
            pointer.setScale(newScale)
            protractor.setScale(newScale)
            ballSpeed = Float(newScale * 100)

            ballSpeedIndicator.text = "\(Int(ballSpeed))"

        }
        if sender.state == .ended{
            // print("Pinch Ended")

            let newScale = sender.scale
            protractorScale = protractorScale * Double(newScale)


        }
    }
```

I set my initial node scale also to 1  as a global variable. So now in the state ended I return that * the pinch scale and the scaling now remains perfectly stable.